# LED Circuit- Beginner seeks help

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design

I am a beginner in electronics and circuits and I decided to make my first circuit. It is an arrangement that spells SPEC with 5mm LED lights. I familiarised myself with the basic concepts (Voltage, amps, Ohms, resistors, e.t.c.). After some research I created this schematic. Would such an arangement work? [image]

The goal:
According to http://ledcalc.com/#calc I set up this arrangement for the letter S (2 leds + 47 Ohm resistor). What I do not know is the way to connect the resistors to the LEDs and in general all the wires. Could someone help me with a small diagram?

[image]

Comment: Have you determined what will be your power source for this project? A 12V battery? A 19 volt computer power supply??

Comment: Do you have a breadboard available? It is a nice way to prototype circuits when you are just starting out.

Comment: You say "the following circuit", but then there is no circuit following.  If the sign will always display the same word, then you aren't stuck with just 7 segments to make letters out of.  You might as well round off the things that should be round.  That way the "S" can look like a "S" instead of a "5" or something else, for example.

Comment: @soosaisteven It is the 5v cable of a Molex connector from a PSU

Comment: @Catsunami Yes I can buy one, but I first want to design it and gain some general knowledge. What I do not understand is how to connect each component, in what order.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Yes you are right, terminology XD. The point of the image is for you to visuallize what I want to make. The issue is that I do not know in what order are the components supposed to be connected.

Comment: The led calc gives you a picture of how they should be wired. +5V to resistor to 1st led anode, 1st led cathode to 2nd led anode, 2nd  Led cathode to Ground. Repeat. http://ledcalc.com/g.php?code=da912f804241563ca76c129d4871fb73&k=1&r=1&l=2&y=null

Comment: @passerby and can I do this as many times as I want? As shown in the edited photo.

Comment: Until the total current needed by the LEDs is more than your power source can provide.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! How do I give  the correct answer ?

Comment: Your schematic is unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you calculated, with 5V, you can only power 2 leds in series. For multiple leds, you have to place them in parallel strings of 2, each with its own resistor.

If you are using a computer ATX power supply, you also have 12V available. To save on resistors, you could power 5 + 100 ohm resistor in series with 12V instead of 5V. Then you can do multiple strings in parallel.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHLtiw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes indeed, this would be better! But can I not connect the resistors and LEDs in a series ? Meaning http://prntscr.com/b2orz4, would this work? And could I continue the same pattern 10 more times ?

Comment: @NikiforosKrikelas ***NO***. As Phil Frost explained. You would need 100+ Volts for something like that, and too many resistors would limit it too.

Comment: OK now I understand. In practice though, how would I connect LEDs on the letter S for example? Is it possible for you to show me?

Answer (score 2):

> Would such an arangement work?

If I'm reading your schematic correctly, no. I think it's something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGFf8X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are a couple problems here. Firstly, each of those LEDs has a forward voltage. If you can't provide this voltage, then the LED just won't turn on. Forward voltage depends on the color of the LED among other things, but for an ordinary RED LED, it's in the neighborhood of 2V.

You have five such LEDs in series, so you need at least 10V to turn them on at all. But you have a 5V battery, so that's not going to work. You'll need a battery with a higher voltage, or a couple batteries in series.

Secondly, you have six resistors in series with the LEDs. While this won't prevent the circuit from working per se, there's no reason to do that. Since this is all one series circuit, the current is the same everywhere in it. How could it not be: there's no other place for the current to go. Those five 470 ohm resistors are equivalent to one 2350 ohm resistor (470*5). You could save some parts by using just one resistor, and probably it's not the right resistance.